# Embed Jenkins Build Data to Angular2 Without API calls

Tags: angular, jenkins

I am trying to embed Jenkins build version and timestamp without using calls to jenkins API & creating custom variables and using artifacts etc.

Right now Jenkins is adding new json file with build number and timestamp when it is building using "Execute Windows batch command", but I'm quite confused if I can access this data. (Maybe i tried wrongly)

```
cd %WORKSPACE%\UI\
del jenkinsBuildData.json
echo "{"buildInfo": {"buildId": %BUILD_NUMBER%, "buildDate": %BUILD_TIMESTAMP%}}" > jenkinsBuildData.json
```

And I want to display it this way:

```
<div *ngFor="data in buildInfo">Company Name: build #{{ data.buildId }} - {{ data.buildDate }}</div>
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It was quite simple.. I set wrong path for my json file.

To output latest build number/date/time or whatever you need from Jenkins you may add json file with certain variables and then access it locally.
*Of course you can do other way - simply update file on every build*

**First Step:**

*Creating file and adding our Jenkins data*

```
cd %WORKSPACE%\UI\
del jenkinsBuildData.json
echo "{"buildInfo": {"buildId": %BUILD_NUMBER%, "buildDate": %BUILD_TIMESTAMP%}}" > jenkinsBuildData.json
```

Basically we are performing next steps:

- Move to app folder
- Delete previously generated file
- Create new file with new data

**Second Step:**

*Accessing our local *.json file*

```
getBuildData() {
  let data;
  this.http.get('./jenkinsData.json').subscribe(res => {
    data = res.json().buildInfo;
    this.buildNumber = data.buildId; // storing build ID in global var
  });
}
```

**Third Step:**

*Output data*

`<div>Company Name: build #{{ buildNumber }}</div>`

No `*ngFor` required